# Crystal Report without using DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

While merging all Crystal Reports into a single project, Errors are shown in the designer.cs file. The error says that

```
"the DataSet I created already contains a definition for the 'RowChangeEvent'  "
```

Anyone could help me in this case?
And also could I know Whether there is any alternative case for creating Crystal report without using DataSet ?

Comment: By *without using DataSet* you mean, without using typed dataset?

Comment: The dataset you are using to create the report is a typed dataset. You can create it using untyped dataset to remove the error.

Comment: @KMan I want to know whether there is a possibility of creating an object of class instead of DataSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at this site as it seems to answer what you are looking for : [How to Generate Crystal Report Using Custom Object Collection](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/558_How_to_Generate_Crystal_Report_Using_Custom_Object_Collection_with_ASP_NET.aspx)

Also, personnaly, I work with crystal reports in the following way:

- I get the dataset that I want to bind to crystal report and save it to disk as xml with the schema (the dataset is filled with real data at runtime)
- I add the xml file to my source control
- I bind my report to that xml file (so designing the report is made easy because you have real data)
- At run-time, you bind the report to a dataset that contains the same schema as your xml file (or custom object collection if you want as described in the link [How to Generate Crystal Report Using Custom Object Collection](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/558_How_to_Generate_Crystal_Report_Using_Custom_Object_Collection_with_ASP_NET.aspx)